# How to Go Back to Login Page after Logged Out React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, redux

I am learning React Native and Redux and building a project.
I have a Profile Page where user can log out. I want to redirect the page to Login after logged out. but I receive below error.
"The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Login'?"

Navigation is built by someone else in this project so I cant change the structure.
Basically in App.js there is structure checking if the user has the authToken or not. if the user does not have it, login page appears and it is outside of the RootNavigation. if the user has authToken, they can see the homepage which is inside of RootNavigation. The problem is that. Login component is outside of the RootNavigation so it doesnt catch it. How can i solve this problem and navigate to login without breaking this structure ?

Below are the codes.

```
App.js

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import store from "./src/Redux/store";
import Login from "./src/Components/Login/Login";
import Profile from "./src/Components/Profile/Profile";
import ProjectList from "./src/Components/ProjectList/ProjectList";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Menu from "./src/Components/Menu/Menu";
import ProfileSettings from "./src/Components/ProfileSettings/ProfileSettings"

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
console.log(store.getState())



const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const RootNavigation = () => {
  const authToken = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.user.access_token);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {authToken ? 
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
       {/* <Stack.Screen name="Project" component={Project} /> */}
       <Stack.Screen name="ProfileSettings" component={ProfileSettings} />
      </Stack.Navigator> :
        <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RootNavigation />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
profileActionType.js

export const UDPATE_USER = "UDPATE_USER";
export const LOG_OUT = "LOG_OUT";
```

```
logOutAction.js
import * as types from "../actions/profileActionType";
import { Alert } from "react-native"; // to show alerts in app

const url = new URL(
    "****" ( i hide my api since it is private )
);


const loggedOut = () => {
    return {
      type: types.LOG_OUT,
      // payload: logOutData.payload,
    
    };
  };

export const logOut = (headers) => {
    console.log("logged out",headers)
    return(dispatch) => {
        return fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            if (json.status === "ok") {
              dispatch(loggedOut({ type: types.LOG_OUT, payload: json }));
              Alert.alert(json.message);
            } else {
              dispatch(loggedOut({ type: types.LOG_OUT, payload: {} }));
              Alert.alert(json.message);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            Alert.alert("Logout Failed", "Some error occured, please try again.");
            dispatch(loggedOut({ type: types.LOG_OUT, payload: {} }));
            console.log(err);
          });
    }
}
```

```
logOutReducer.js

import * as types from "../actions/profileActionType";

const initialProfileState = {};

  const logOutReducer = (state = initialProfileState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.LOG_OUT:
        return {
          ...state,
          user: action.payload,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export default logOutReducer;
```

```
Profile.js

import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import {
  useFonts,
  NunitoSans_400Regular,
  NunitoSans_700Bold,
  NunitoSans_800ExtraBold,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import styles from "./ProfileStyleSheet";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import {logOut} from '../../Redux/actions/logOutAction'



const Profile = ({navigation}) => {
  userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    NunitoSans_400Regular,
    NunitoSans_700Bold,
    NunitoSans_800ExtraBold,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  const token = userInfo.access_token
  console.log("logout token", token)

  const headers = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  };

  const handleLogOut = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(logOut(headers))
    navigation.navigate("Login")
  }

  const navigationProfileSettings = () => {
    navigation.navigate("ProfileSettings")
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Profile</Text>
      <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.tinyLogo}
            source={{
              uri: `${userInfo.user.avatar}`,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.titleName}>{userInfo.user.name}</Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Id facilisi cum
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.linksLogoContainer}>
        <View>
          {/* <NotificationLogo style={styles.tinyLogo}/> */}
          <Text style={styles.description}>Notification</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.line} />
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigationProfileSettings}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>Profile Settings</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.line} />
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogOut}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>Log Out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}


export default Profile
```

Comment: the `authToken`shoud be handled by an state or you should refresh the page

Comment: Ho can i make this ? I cant refresh the page though since it is a mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this problem, I have come up with a solution and it is to reset the state because I needed to clear my token. the project has a logic if the user is logged in or not by the token. and changes the navigation. so the code below in store.js will clear the state and will log us out and redirect us to the login page. we can clear the state by state=undefined.

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  logOutReducer: logOutReducer,
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOG_OUT) {
    state = undefined;
  }
  return appReducer(state, action)
}

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```